# 2 Arrays no foreach apartir de um formulario

Tags: php

Boa noite pessoal! Suponha que eu tenho esses arrays:
`alimento[]` e `quantidade[]` 
Como faço p/ colocar os 2 array no foreach,  eu só consigo colocar apenas 1 =/

Segue meu código:

```
<form method="POST">
    Feijao<input type="checkbox" name="alimento[]" value="Feijao - "> Quantidade<input type="number" name="quantidade[]"><br>
    Arroz<input type="checkbox" name="alimento[]" value="Arroz"> Quantidade<input type="number" name="quantidade[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Processar">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['alimento'])){

 $alimento = $_POST['alimento'];
 $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
 foreach($alimento as $k){
    echo $k;
 }
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você também pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($alimento as $key => $value){
   echo "Alimento: {$value}";
   echo "Quantidade: {$quantidade[$key]}";
}
```

Comment: Justamente o que eu precisava amigo.. vlw amigoooo

Answer (score 1):

O **foreach()** só trabalhará com um array por vez, então deverá ser um para cada. Mas se ambas as listas tem o mesmo número de elementos faça algo usando o bom e velho **for()**:

```
<?php
   // ...
   for($i=0; $i<count($alimentos); $i++){
        echo $alimentos[$i];
        echo $quantidade[$i];
   }
   // ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O `foreach` suporta apenas uma coleção e não duas.

No entanto consegue fazer o que pretende utilizando [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) que combina os nomes e as quantidades num só array, transformando-o num array associativo em que os nomes são as chaves e as quantidades os valores:

```
$alimentosQtd = array_combine($alimento, $quantidade);
foreach ($alimentosQtd as $alim => $qtd){
    echo $alim, $qtd;
}
```

Outra solução é aceder pela posição utilizando um `for` em vez de `foreach`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($alimentos); ++$i){
    echo $alimento[$i], $quantidade[$i];
}
```

Em que `$alimento[i]` corresponde a cada um dos alimentos e `$quantidade[$i]` a cada uma das quantidades.